# How to solve equations like $2 \sin(x) = \cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

My mathbook tells me that it isn't possible to solve this:

$$2 \sin(x) = \cos(x)$$

But Wolfram Alpha gives the following answer:

$$x = 2\cdot\left(\pi n-\tan^{-1}(2\pm\sqrt{5})\right)$$

Is it possible to do this, without the help of a calculator?

Comment: Well you can find $\tan x$ easily enough the way you've written it - have you got the question right.

Comment: The way you wrote it would just be $\tan(x)=\frac 1 2$,  so your answer would be $\arctan (\frac 1 2)$

Comment: (...together with the solutions obtained by exploiting the symmetry of the tangent function.)

Comment: Is the question, then, how does one show that WolframAlpha's expression is the solution (or equivalently, equivalent to the solution described here in the comments)?

Comment: Are both answers correct then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be using $\tan\frac x2=t$ so $\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$.

Here $2 \sin x= \cos x$ implies $t^2+4t-1=0$ from which $\tan \frac x2=2\pm\sqrt{5}$. Hence the answer of Wolfram.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Merci beaucoup professeur.